# php getting column names for older version of ms-access (.mdb)

Tags: php, database, ms-access, pdo

**PDOStatement::getColumnMeta** does not supported Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb). How can I get field names dynamically with PDO?

***Note:*** I **would not** know the sql query beforehand. **$sql** below is just for demonstration.

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver 
                (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\database.mdb;Uid=Admin");

// Sample SQL could be used
$sql = "SELECT name, SUM(b) AS sumvalue FROM table GROUP BY name";

$result = $dbh->query($sql);
$data = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $result->columnCount(); $i++) {
        $col = $result->getColumnMeta($i);   //<------ This line not supported

        $fieldName = $col['name'];
        if (!isset($data[$fieldName])) $data[$fieldName] = [];
        array_push($data[$fieldName], $row[$fieldName]);
    }
}

// Get JSON result
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: @Mike Get JSON result from SQL query. While I won't know the SQL query beforehand.

Comment: Why can't you just do `$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`? That puts the column names in an associative array, which it looks like you're trying to do here somewhat.

Comment: @Mike Trying $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `getColumnMeta()` to get the column name. If you're using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` the column names will be the keys of an associative array. You can just loop over this:

```
$results = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$data = [];
foreach ($results as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

// Get JSON result
echo json_encode($data);
```

Note: You can also make this your default fetch mode for that connection:

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver 
            (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\database.mdb;Uid=Admin");
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This way you don't need to specify it every time you `fetch()`/`fetchAll()`.

Comment: Thanks, this is all I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try anything like that:

```
<?php
$fName = '';
$sumVal = '';
$pdoStr = 'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\database.mdb;Uid=Admin"';
$dbh = new PDO($pdoStr);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT name, SUM(b) AS sumvalue FROM table GROUP BY name";
$result = $dbh->query($sql);
$data = $result->fetchAll();
// here, you only have two fields, "name" and "sumvalue", so, you need to use these fields only, so this will work
foreach($data as $row) {
    $fName = row['Name'];
    $sumVal = row['sumvalue'];
    // ...
}
?>
```

Hope which help!

Peace!

Comment: I need to obtain field names on the run. I do not know the field names beforehand.

Comment: this is de most simple way to get values from columns in a PDO statement, as PDO string is which make the diference, after connected with a string, the commands is the same for all

Comment: so you need to loop from your table and get each column by its name, note that name is the name of the column in the table as they are named finically or named programmatically like "sumvalue"

Comment: Could be both finically or programmatically. I won't know the sql query beforehand.

Comment: fisically is "b", programmatically is "sumvalue", you can't get a inexistent column

Comment: In this example, I need to get 'name' and 'sumvalue' as result.

Comment: and in my example it will be returned as value, try it to see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167445/discussion-between-clinton-lam-and-armando-marques-sobrinho).